# Spork and cache_classes problem with rspec, factory_girl and datamapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, datamapper, spork, factory-bot

I've got a problem with Spork test server.

If I set config.cache_classes = false in config/environments/test.rb then specs start to rasie errors.

```
Failure/Error: task = Factory(:something, :foo => @foo, :bar => @bar)
     DataMapper::ImmutableError:
       Immutable resource cannot be modified
```

This is my spec_helper.rb:

```
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  if ENV['CODE_COVERAGE'] == '1'
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'webmock/rspec'
  require 'factory_girl'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/controllers/shared/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :mocha
    config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    config.include UrlHelper

    config.before(:each) do
      repository(:default) do
        transaction = DataMapper::Transaction.new(repository)
        transaction.begin
        repository.adapter.push_transaction(transaction)
      end
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      repository(:default).adapter.pop_transaction.try(:rollback)
    end

  end
end

# This code will be run each time you run your specs.
Spork.each_run do
  # reload factories
  Factory.definition_file_paths = Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "spec", "factories")]
  Factory.find_definitions

  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
  LoggedEvent.all.destroy!

end
```

When I have config.cache_classes = true, then everything works well, but It not reload me a models, controllers classes, so I don't see a point in using spork in this case.

I tried to add to spec_helper.rb something like this, when cache is true:

```
Spork.each_run do
    Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/models/*.rb").sort.each { |file| load file }
end
```

But I don't like this solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add:

```
ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
```

to the end of the prefork block. this will take care of clearing the models.

Also, you want to move that rspec configure inclusions to Spork.each_run, same goes with requiring spec support and shared files.

This works, I use this setup in 2 projects w/o any troubles.

Comment: Wait, so does `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` belong in prefork or each_run? I've seen conflicting stories. Neither seems to work for me, both causing loading issues: "expected xxxx to define xxxx." Also, is it `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` alone that solves the problem? Or is that needed in conjunction with the each_run example in the original question?

Comment: I don't know why, but my project just suddenly started doing this, for no apparent reason.  I ended up putting the Dependencies.clear in my Spork.each_run, and it worked for me.  I don't have my Rspec.config in each_run, just: FactoryGirl.reload and ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear.   Hope that helps.

Comment: ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear should be added at the end of the prefork, not each_run

Comment: Unfortunately this solution didn't work for me either - I've tried it on a couple of projects now

Comment: You guys want to make sure that your test db has been migrated. Hope all is well, @PeterNixey =) Great seeing you here :-)

Comment: @Abdo - likewise buddy. Hope all's well

Comment: This throws errors for me - some weird thing where it's trying to instantiate a module. Haven't tracked it down though, so maybe it's very specific to my app.

Comment: This approach is sort of a workaround. My guess is that the real problem is that you have code running in Spork.prefork that's loading models. I had a similar issue and I was able to debug it by calling `spork --diagnose`. It will list all of the files loaded by Spork and a backtrace of what loaded each file. In my case I had an initializer referencing a controller, causing issues with that controller not reloading on each test run.

Answer (score 8):

## Try ActionDispatch::Reloader

In addition to setting `config.cache_classes = false` in `config/environments/test.rb`, the following seems to make DataMapper and Spork play nicely for our team:

```
Spork.each_run do

  # Routes
  MyApp::Application.reload_routes!

  if Spork.using_spork?
    # Reload all app files
    ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup!
    ActionDispatch::Reloader.prepare!

    # All factories
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

end
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't expect it to, but this seemed to fix my problems with Mongoid and Spork. All the other documentation on the subject ([Spork.trap_method Jujitsu](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu) and `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear`) didn't work at all. I was even able to get rid of my extra trap on `Rails::Mongoid.load_models`.

Comment: This approach actually includes ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear and more. Calling ActionDispatch::Reloader.cleanup! and prepare! is exactly what reload! does in the rails console. +1

Answer (score 0):

Hi I wanted to share what helped me running test again.
It turns out I had to add the `shared_connection` trick as spork was complaining about connection lost.
After this I had to shift the `dependency.clear` line at at the end of the block as it was caching my models.

```
Spork.each_run do
  # ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear # <-- moved this line at end of block as suggested by @solnic
  ActiveRecord::Base.instantiate_observers
  MyApp::Application.reload_routes!
  FactoryGirl.reload

  class ActiveRecord::Base
    mattr_accessor :shared_connection
    @@shared_connection = nil

    def self.connection
      @@shared_connection || retrieve_connection
    end
  end
  ActiveRecord::Base.shared_connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection

  ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear # <-- line moved here

end if Spork.using_spork?
```