# Ruby/Rails: AssociationTypeMismatch with the correct association, but it expects different object id? Whaaa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, capybara

So, I'm getting a pretty strange error here... I tried to isolate it but it's quasi-intermittent.  I'm kinda wondering if it has something to do with using capybara with a javascript driver, because this isn't happening in my non-capybara tests.  Here it is:

```
Failure/Error: @existing_user, household = create_new_user_and_household
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch:
 User(#57141560) expected, got User(#42098260)
# ./app/models/household.rb:64:in `block in create_new_household'
# ./app/models/household.rb:62:in `new'
# ./app/models/household.rb:62:in `create_new_household'
# ./spec/support/spec_helpers.rb:55:in `create_new_user_and_household'
# ./spec/integration/accepting_an_invitation_spec.rb:21:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here's the block in question:

```
household = Household.new attributes, do |h|
  h.account = user.account || Account.create(user: user)
end
```

Pretty basic, and works fine when I do it manually in the rails console.

I'm not sure what else to tell you guys... but I'm happy to provide more info.

I'm using `rspec` for all of my testing.

Comment: Do you have cache_classes turned on for tests?

Comment: no, I turned them off in test.rb

Comment: ah, I turned them back on and it worked!  I'd read somewhere to turn them off... maybe that no longer applies...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer, as [Frederick Cheung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1064226/frederick-cheung) pointed out was to set `cache_classes` to `true` in `test.rb`.

This supposedly conflicts with spork, which is why I was told to turn it off in the first place--since you want spork to re-load your models and whatnot whenever you run another test.  The solution is to set `cache_classes` to `true` but also put `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear` in your spork prefork block.

References:

1. [ActiveSupport:Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5913255/spork-and-cache-classes-problem-with-rspec-factory-girl-and-datamapper)
2. [Reloading Models](http://my.rails-royce.org/2012/01/14/reloading-models-in-rails-3-1-when-usign-spork-and-cache_classes-true/)
3. [Spork tips](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujutsu)
4. [Spork cache_classes explanation](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/05/09/spork-testing-tip-caching-classes/)